# How to override a method Inside another method using c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, overriding

I'm new to C# and I need to figure out how to override a class method inside a new class method without implementing inheritance, in Java I can do this:

```
Class classA{
  void method1(){
       statements ....
       ....
       classB obj = new classBb(){
            @override
            void someMethod(){ //from ClassB
              statements ....
              ....
            }
       };  
   }
}
```

I want to achieve the same in **C#**.

Comment: As far as I know - that's not possible in .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that in C#. If some part of the implementation is call-site specific, you could use a *delegate*, though. The `void method2()` signature maps to `Action` (no parameters / return-value), so:

```
class classB {
    private readonly Action method2;
    public classB(Action method2) {
        if(method2==null) throw new ArgumentNullException("method2");
        this.method2 = method2;
    }
    public void SomeMethod() {
         ... that uses what was method2()
        method2();
    }
}
```

then:

```
classB obj = new classB(() => {
   // statements...
});
```

with alternative identical syntax:

```
classB obj = new classB(delegate {
   // statements...
});
```

or:

```
classB obj = new classB(delegate() {
   // statements...
});
```

Comment: thanks @Marc Gravell but instead of passing an anonymous method to ClassB constructor and calling it in SomeMethod() we can create an anonymous method inside SomMethod() block right..!

Comment: @Kaviraj yes, but that defeats the purpose; the entire point here seems to be that the implementation is specific to the call-site of `classA.method1`; putting the implementation inside `SomeMethod()` does not allow that - unless you mean "we could pass a delegate parameter to `SomeMethod`", then sure; but I can't comment on whether that is suitable because you don't show where `SomeMethod()` is invoked.